# side-menu(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i try to add side menu in my app but give me this error message in console (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

this is homepage.html

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
  <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
  <ion-title>
     Menus
</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

 <ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
 <ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)">
    Home
  </button>
  <button ion-item (click)="openPage(sign)">
    sign
  </button>
    <button ion-item  menuClose (click)="closeMenu()">
    Close Menu
  </button>
</ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

  <ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

this is homepage.ts

```
export class HomePage {
 private rootPage;
 private sign;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menu:MenuController) {
  menu.enable(true);

this.rootPage = HomePage;

   this.sign = SignupPage;
   }


  openPage(p) {
  this.rootPage = p;
}
}
```

this a picture for error

[image]

this is main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

 import { AppModule } from './app.module';

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser- 
   dynamic';

 import { AppModule } from './app.module';

 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

why give me error for name?? any help please

Comment: Can you please add you main.ts source code too?

Comment: Phil  ok i add it

Comment: which version on ionic are you using ? Check that you have the entryComponents setup correctely in you app.module.ts it should be saying entryComponents: [MyApp] where MyApp is your main Page

Comment: may be you bind variable in your any one of pages and not declare on ts e.g.[(ngModel)]="name" but not decare in ts please decalre variable on ts file.